# Close youtube popup window by clicking 'x' is not working using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, popupwindow

Trying to close a Youtube popup window by clicking **'x'** button present on the top right corner, but I'm getting the following error message:

> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is
>   not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Tried the bellow code:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("close")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='close']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[class='close']")).click();
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",
driver.findElement(By.className("close")));
```

HTML:

```
<div id="videoModal" class="modal fade in" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="videoModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" style="display: block;">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-body">
<button class="close" aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">×</button>
<div>
<iframe width="100%" height="350" allowfullscreen="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/SQFKxxKMIxc?autoplay=1"/>
</div>
```

**Screenshot:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3IXe.png

```
public Boolean closeVideoPopup(){
    try{
        driver.findElement(By.id("video-how-to")).click();
        driver.waitForPageLoad();
        driver.findElement(By.className("close")).click();
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        logger.info("Exception occurred: "+ e.getMessage().toString().substring(0, Integer.parseInt(TestConstants.ERRCHARCOUNT)));
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you consider showing us which **'x' button** you are referring to and show us some of your work please? Thanks

Comment: @AakashSingh can you also add a print-screen of the popup, preferably with a wide open browser console after you `Inspect`ed the **x** you are trying to click.

Comment: @Dev Added the screenshot link and the code I have written.

Comment: @iamdanchiv  Added a link to Screenshot.

Comment: @AakashSingh can you confirm that the **Youtube** is in fact inside an iframe? And if so, can you update the print-screen with one that shows us the entire `<iframe>` tags (with the enclosed content) ?

Comment: @iamdanchiv Yes, youtube is inside an iframe but the 'x' button is outside it. There is only one iframe in this popup and that's of youtube, rest are in the page behind it. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sBG9.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUNva.png
Couldn't find a way to show just the iframes. If you can help me with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It works using the complete xpath now**

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='videoModal']/div/div/div/button[@class='close']")).click();
```

**Steps to do this using Sikuli:**

Add Sikuli jar in your project or add as a dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
            <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Take the screenshot of element using Sikuli IDE. 
Steps to install and use Sikuli IDE:
http://www.sikuli.org/downloadrc3.html

Write the below code:

```
Screen screen = new Screen();
Pattern image = new Pattern(filePath\\xbutton.png");
screen.click(image);
```

click method of Screen class will help to click on the element

Answer (score 0):

This selector should work but will be more efficient if you replace it with your suited markup:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'close')]"));
```

Or, since we know the sought element is a div:

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'close')]"));
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some other element is overlapping your pop-up. Thus, you can use explicit waiting for the element in order for it to become visible.

```
 WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 90);
 wait.untill(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.className("close")));
```

... or find out the element which is overlapping and wait for the element to disappears.

Both ways you can try.